# Detect Intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql-8.4

```
id_person  transaction  internation_in internation_out  
1            456465     2015-01-01     2015-02-01  
2            564564     2015-02-03     2015-04-02   
3            4564654    2015-01-01     2015-01-05  
4            4564646    2015-01-01     2015-02-04  
4            4564656    2015-03-01     2015-04-15  
4            87899465   2015-05-16     2015-05-25  
5            56456456   2015-01-01     2105-01-08  
5            45456546   2015-02-04     2015-03-04
```

I want to know how to group by `id_person` the difference (Interval in hours) between the `internation_out` from the first transaction with the `internation_in` of the next transaction.

I probe with lag and lead but I can't group by `id_person`

I Want this Result using id_person 4 for example

id_person  transaction  Gap
4  4564646   Null

4 4564656  The result of (2015-02-04- 2015-03-01)
4 87899465  The result of (2015-04-15- 2015-05-16)

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample results.

Answer (score 0):

If your time periods are not overlapping (and yours are not), then there is a simple calculation for the gaps:  it is the total number of days from the beginning to the end minus the total on each row.  So, you don't need `lead()` or `lag()`:

```
select id_person,
       (case when count(*) > 1
             then (max(internation_out) - min(internation_in) -
                   sum(internation_out - internation_in)
                  )
        end) as gap_duration
from table t
group by id_person;
```

Note that this returns `NULL` if there is only one row for the person.  If you want `0`, then you don't need the `case`.